# OPENJSON on JSON with double empty array

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have this JSON

```
    {
  "OrderHeader": [[
    {
      "OrderID": 100,
      "CustomerID": 2000,
      "OrderDetail": 
        {
          "ProductID":2000, 
          "UnitPrice":350      
        }
    }
  ]]
}
```

After the OrderHeader there is two [[.

I am not able to parse this JSON using the OPENJSON TSQL Command.

If it was just one [ then i would parse like

```
DECLARE @JSONData varchar(MAX) = '
{
  "OrderHeader": [
    {
      "OrderID": 100,
      "CustomerID": 2000,
  
      "OrderDetail": 
        {
          "ProductID": 2000, 
          "UnitPrice": 350      
        }
    }
  ]
}
'
SELECT
    OrderID, CustomerID, ProductID, UnitPrice
FROM OPENJSON (@JSONData)
WITH (
    OrderHeader nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON
) AS Orders
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Orders.OrderHeader)
WITH 
(
    OrderID INT, 
    CustomerID INT,
    OrderDetail nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON
) AS OrderDetail
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OrderDetail.OrderDetail)
WITH
(
    ProductID INT, 
    UnitPrice INT
) ;
```

Please help to Parse with its with TWO [ as in the first sample

Thank you.

Comment: You can also access nested arrays by specifying the path in OPENJSON, e.g.: `OrderHeader nvarchar(MAX) '$.OrderHeader[0][0]' AS JSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to double up the `OPENJSON`s, though I would personally suggest, if you can, fixing the JSON:

```sql
DECLARE @JSONData nvarchar(MAX) = N'
{
  "OrderHeader": [[
    {
      "OrderID": 100,
      "CustomerID": 2000,
  
      "OrderDetail": 
        {
          "ProductID": 2000, 
          "UnitPrice": 350      
        }
    }
  ]]
}';

SELECT V.OrderID,
       V.CustomerID,
       OD.ProductID,
       OD.UnitPrice
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData)
     WITH (OrderHeader nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) OJ
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OJ.OrderHeader) OH
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OH.[value])
                 WITH (OrderID int,
                       CustomerID int,
                       OrderDetail nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) V
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.OrderDetail)
                 WITH (ProductID int,
                       UnitPrice int) OD;
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. Its working... correcting the JSON was hard, since it is coming from some third party service. Thank you once agin

Comment: You're welcome, @user2921359 . If the answer solved the problem, please do mark the answer as the solution, so that future users know the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The statement depends on the structure of the parsed JSON ( ... I hope I understand it correctly) and you may simplify your statement using only two `OPENJSON()` calls:

JSON (with one additional item in the nested JSON array):

```
DECLARE @JSONData varchar(MAX) = '
{
  "OrderHeader": [[
    {
      "OrderID": 100,
      "CustomerID": 2000,
      "OrderDetail": 
        {
          "ProductID":2000, 
          "UnitPrice":350      
        }
    },
    {
      "OrderID": 200,
      "CustomerID": 3000,
      "OrderDetail": 
        {
          "ProductID":2000, 
          "UnitPrice":350      
        }
    }
  ]]
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.OrderHeader') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
   OrderID INT '$.OrderID', 
   CustomerID INT '$.CustomerID',
   ProductID INT '$.OrderDetail.ProductID', 
   UnitPrice INT' $.OrderDetail.UnitPrice'
) j2
```

Result:

```
OrderID CustomerID ProductID UnitPrice
100     2000       2000      350
200     3000       2000      350
```

Finally, if the `$.OrderHeader` JSON array always has a single item, the following statement is also an option:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.OrderHeader[0]') WITH (
   OrderID INT '$.OrderID', 
   CustomerID INT '$.CustomerID',
   ProductID INT '$.OrderDetail.ProductID', 
   UnitPrice INT' $.OrderDetail.UnitPrice'
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Learned something new from you.

Comment: @user2921359, I'm glad you've found a solution to your problem.